# Adding data in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck with this part that if I have to click the `sample` activeX button in the sheet, the data that is saved from another sheet will be displayed in column O starting from row 4. And if the user click `sample2` button, the changes made in column O for the `sample` button will then be saved in Column A and the data saved for `sample2` button that is column B will then replace the data in column O.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
Dim main, data As Worksheet
Dim i, lRow As Integer

Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

For i = 4 To 18 ' starts in 4 because it is where I want to start to copy the data
    lRow = lRow + 1
    main.Range("O" & i) = data.Range("A" & lRow)
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Main][image: data]
This only copies the data from the Data sheet. But dunno how to do the reverse one that if I click another button, the data that is currently in column O will be saved in Column A in the data sheet. Thanks.

Comment: The above code Takes the Values from `Main` and places it into `Data`. While you are stating: "This only copies the data from the Data sheet"?

Comment: What I meant is from the data that is Copied is from the Data Sheet to the Main Sheet/

Comment: Be careful when you declare several varaibles in the same line you still have to write the type for each of them otherwise they will be Variant: `Dim main As Worksheet, data As Worksheet` and `Dim i As Integer, lRow As Integer`. Also, there is no need for a loop as your range is not dynamic: `main.Range("O4:O18").Value = data.Range("A4:A18").Value` is enough

Comment: Can you be more clear when you explain what you want to do? When we click on `Sample`: Cloumn A of `data` Worksheet is copied in Column O of  `main` worksheet. When we click on `Sample2`: Column O of 
`main` is copied in Cloumn A of `data` (the exact reverse of `Sample`). But what with column B replacing column O ?? Could you edit your question?

Answer (score -1):

Simply change the following:

```
data.Range("A" & lRow) = main.Range("O" & i)
```

into:

```
data.Range("A" & lRow) = data.Range("O" & i)
```

Now you place the Values from `Data "O"` into `Data "A"`

Comment: This copying of data from main to data sheet should only be done if the user clicks another button.

Comment: @ramj you can use your code you have for the new button and change what I posted.